# Multiple conditions in BeautifulSoup: Text=True & IMG Alt=True

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

is there a way to use multiple conditions in BeautifulSoup?

These are the two conditions I like to use together:

Get text:

```
soup.find_all(text=True)
```

Get img alt:

```
soup.find_all('img', title=True):
```

I know I can do it separately but I would like to get it together to keep the flow of the HTML.

The reason I'm doing this is because only BeautifulSoup extract the hidden text by css: Display None.

When you use driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text you get the img alt att, but unfortunately not the hidden text by css: display:none.

I appreciate your help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.find_all()` returns only texts or tags, but you can make your own function that returns texts from the soup and text from the `alt=` attributes.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag, NavigableString


txt = '''
Some text
<img alt="Some alt" src="#" />
Some other text
'''

def traverse(s):
    for c in s.contents:
        if isinstance(c, Tag):
            if c.name == 'img' and 'alt' in c.attrs:
                yield c['alt']
            yield from traverse(c)
        elif isinstance(c, NavigableString):
            yield c


soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for text in traverse(soup):
    print(text.strip())
```

Prints:

```
Some text
Some alt
Some other text
```

Comment: It works like charm bro, thanks! I have a question, what's the difference to use "yield from traverse(c)" or "yield from c". I think both have the same outcome but I'm curious why to use the same function... I would have never thought.

Comment: Is there a way to storage the results in a string variable?

Comment: Got it, just created a str variable inside the for loop and it's done! Thank you!