# How to scrape Amazon IMG Alt Attributes with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm having a really hard time trying to scrape Amazon, my code works on every average page but when it comes to Amazon it's really frustrating.

I know I can use "FindAll" but I'm using this approach to "keep the flow" and get text and img alt simultaneous:

See
[Multiple conditions in BeautifulSoup: Text=True & IMG Alt=True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63424162/multiple-conditions-in-beautifulsoup-text-true-img-alt-true)

This is my code:

```
url = "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Health-Personal-Care-Foot-Arch-Supports/zgbs/hpc/3780091"

import requests
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag, NavigableString
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

def get_raw_text(s):
    for t in s.contents:
        if isinstance(t, Tag):
            if t.name == 'img' and 'alt' in t.attrs:
                yield t['alt']
            yield from get_raw_text(t)

for text in get_raw_text(soup):
    print(text)
```

and I get nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the `HTML` parser to `html5lib`. First do this `pip install html5lib` and then try again with this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36'}
url = "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Health-Personal-Care-Foot-Arch-Supports/zgbs/hpc/3780091"
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)


soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')


def get_raw_text(s):
    for t in s.contents:
        if isinstance(t, Tag):
            if t.name == 'img' and 'alt' in t.attrs:
                yield t['alt']
            yield from get_raw_text(t)


for text in get_raw_text(soup):
    print(text)
```

Output:

```
Dr. Scholl’s Tri-Comfort Insoles // Comfort for Heel, Arch and Ball of Foot with Targeted Cushioning and Arch Support…
Dr. Scholl’s Sport Insoles // Superior Shock Absorption and Arch Support to Reduce Muscle Fatigue and Stress on Lower…
Copper Compression Copper Arch Support - 2 Plantar Fasciitis Braces/Sleeves. Guaranteed Highest Copper Content. Foot…
Dr. Scholl’s Extra Support Insoles // Superior Shock Absorption and Reinforced Arch Support for Big & Tall Men To Reduce…
Arch Support,3 Pairs Compression Fasciitis Cushioned Support Sleeves, Plantar Fasciitis Foot Relief Cushions for Plantar…
LLSOARSS Plantar Fasciitis Feet Sandal with Arch Support - Best Orthotic flip Flops for Flat Feet，Heel Pain- for Women
Pcssole’s 3/4 Orthotics Shoe Insoles High Arch Supports Shoe Insoles for Plantar Fasciitis, Flat Feet, Over-Pronation…
and so on...
```

Comment: If you find my answer useful please upvote and/or accept it.